# How do I convert Garmin waypoint in decimal coordinates to ArcGIS viewpoints

Tags: arcgis-runtime

I have a few waypoints of a South Dakota Trail from a Garmin device in the decimal format (43.42330, -103.48474). In ArcGIS Runtime Android SDK 100.x.x I am opening a basemap and trying to add a simple marker symbol of a red dot on it.

```
ArcGISMap map = new ArcGISMap(Basemap.Type.TOPOGRAPHIC, 43.42330, -103.48474, 16);
    // create an initial viewpoint with a point and scale

    Point point = new Point(44.96971, -103.77460, SpatialReferences.getWebMercator());
    Viewpoint vp = new Viewpoint(point, 7500);
```

Which is displayed while the app get loaded fine. Now I want to add a Simple Marker using this code on top of the map.

```
    SimpleMarkerSymbol symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.Style.CIRCLE, Color.RED, 12); //size 12, style of circle

    //add a new graphic with a new point geometry
    Point graphicPoint = new Point(43.42330, -103.48474, SpatialReferences.getWebMercator());
    Graphic graphic = new Graphic(graphicPoint, symbol);
    graphicsOverlay.getGraphics().add(graphic);
```

Currently the red dot is off the Gulf of Guinea in West Africa. 
What am I doing wrong. I think my Map zoom and Point scale are out of proposition?  How would I fix this point to show up in the right place?

Answer (score 1):

Your coordinates are in lat/Long's (decimal degrees) not in web Mercator which would be meters. Instead try WGS-1984.  SpatialReference(4326);